# How to design a REST application with support for permissions to parts of the model?

Tags: java, rest, domain-driven-design

I work on an Java application exposing a REST API. I follow Domain Driven Design. The REST API returns agregate roots along with all the entities inside the agregate.

The model is a set of Java POJO classes and does not contain any refereces to infrastructure code and the REST support is provided by Jersey with Jackson serialization.

The new requirement is to add support for returning/not returing parts of the model based on the user permissions, e.g. for `GET /user/{user_id}`:

- regular users should get `{login: "john", name: "John Smith"}`
- while admin users should get `{id: 1, login: "john", name: "John Smith", active: "true"}`

There are a couple of options that I consider:

1. create DTO classes, like `UserForAdminsDTO`, `UserForRegularUserDTO`
2. extend model classes (by inheritance or composition) and provide an implementation that will override (in case of inheritance) the methods that should not return data for regular users, e.g. `Long getId() { return null; }`
3. create custom serializers/deserializers, which will use custom annotations on the model, e.g. `@OnlyAvailableFor(ADMIN)`

Do you know other approaches? What do you think about the three I have provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question with DDD, so you should think about whether or not you are leaking domain logic into the service layer with your approaches. This would be the case if both the data (the user information in your example) and the permissions model are part of the same BC.

If the permissions model is either a separate BC, or just considered infrastructure and not part of any domain at all, then your approach of doing the filtering in the service layer is correct.

### Now to the technical part of your question:

I recommend against creating different DTOs, because it means duplicating code in the DTO, which in turn is a duplication of your interface specification.

It is better to reduce the admin/no admin decision to one place: Your application remains maintainable, and it's impossible to introduce "half done" bugs. **Approach #3 in your question is the only one that fulfills that requirement, so I'd go with that one.**

With #1, duplication is obvious, and with #2 you'd still have to change the DTO **and** the mapper when moving stuff from user-visibility to admin-visibility.

Comment: thanks @theDmi, I also find #3 as the best approach. BTW, I have started following the domain-driven-design tag and it seems you answer 100% of the questions with this tag, impressive! keep up good work! thanks

Comment: @AdamSiemion Thanks! Yeah I find the topic very interesting and think the whole software industry could benefit from knowing more about DDD. That does not mean that DDD should be used everywhere, but knowing its concepts is certainly a good thing.